# Filing mother's B2 visa extension - Do I need to mention myself as Preparer & Interpreter mandatorily?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, covid-19, visa-extensions

Mother's B2 visa stay expiring 17-May-20. Need to file extension. Started filling online I-539 on USCIS portal, have few questions:

1. Do I need to mandatorily mention my name/details, if I am preparing application and interpreting questions (English to native language)?
2. How long extended stay I can request for her?
3. In "In Care Of Name" - Do I need to mandatorily mention my name or can it be left blank (her name is not on apartment lease)?

Comment: The form should be completed truthfully. If a question on the form asks if someone assisted the filer, and if so, to identify themselves, then you must answer truthfully. To be more precise, _your mother_ — whose form it is — must answer all the questions truthfully.

Comment: Will the post office deliver letters and notices addressed to your mother at the address she is stating on the form?

Comment: Why wouldn't you mention your name?  Putting an "in care of name" reinforces the perception that your mother does not live in the US.  For an nonimmigrant extension of stay in the US, that's precisely the impression you want to create.

Comment: Thanks for above inputs. (1) For online I-539 application for visa extension due to COVID-19, is there any standard reason format? (2) My mother's return travel ticket was on 20-March-2020 which was later cancelled by the airline due this situation and asked me to book same ticket in the future once the air-travel resumes. In this case, what should I provided in response to "arrangements you have made to depart from the United States" on the application? (3) Do I need to provide I-134 also?